# What is the template for this paper?

Tags: typography, document-classes

I find those latex document really nice and would like to know if anyone knows how to obtain a similar look and feel ?

http://zll22.user.srcf.net/EtaleCohomology.pdf

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/candelori/ThesisFinal.pdf

Comment: There isn't that much customization required other than fancyhdr, selecting the right font and doing a custom coverpage.

Comment: Do you know what the font is ?

Comment: @ortholle: See [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)